# Battery life different depending on desktop?

Tags: battery

I switched all of my computers over to Linux over the last month or so and I'm wondering if there is a difference in battery life between Gnome, Mate, KDE, or others?

And is it common to get worse battery life with Linux than with Windows? Even with tlp?

Thank you all in advance for the help.

Jenn

Comment: This *may* get marked as primarily opinion based - There are things you can do (like Tlp) to help extend battery life - but it's been so long, I don't recall what my battery life was like anymore.  Gnome is considered a heavy desktop - lots of stuff and feathers.  Lubuntu, and Xubuntu are two lightweight versions of Ubuntu, and the others are somewhere in-between.  Ubuntu Studio loads up a huge variety of media manipulation applications.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response Charles. I'll give L or X a try.

Comment: If you already have Ubuntu installed, you can simply install the X or L desktop.  Please note that although you can switch between desktops at login, the new desktops will install additional programs and there is no easy way to revert to a 'stock' ubuntu.